# Upgrading Rails app from 3.2.6 to 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-3-upgrade

I have a Rails app that was created using Rails `3.2.6`.  Now that `3.2.8` has been released, is this all I need to do to update the app?

1. Edit `Gemfile`, changing the line `gem 'rails', '3.2.6'` to gem `'rails', '3.2.8'`
2. Run `bundle update rails`

What about other Rails-generated entries in the `Gemfile`, such as `sass-rails`, `coffee-rails` and `uglifier`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hat tip to Santiago Pastorino (Rails Core Team Member), who confirmed this is all that's required:

1. Edit `Gemfile`, changing the line `gem 'rails', '3.2.6'` to `gem 'rails', '3.2.8'`
2. Run `bundle update rails`

[Confirmation tweet.](https://twitter.com/spastorino/status/233905112039432193)

Answer (score 1):

After running `$ bundle install`, run `$ rake rails:update`

Comment: `rake rails:update` appeared to update all of the following files, but none of them changed so I don't think it's required when upgrading from `3.2.6` to `3.2.8`.  Thanks though!