# How do I upgrade to the latest version of ruby on rails 3.2.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been away from programming for a few months but I'm back now and surprised to rails already at version 3.2.8. I feel slightly rusty and forgot how to successfully upgrade my ruby on rails version to the latest.

I'm currently using version 3.2.3

Is there a standard way of upgrading? I remember the last time I upgraded I had to modify some lines in the gemfile. A google search didn't help so I would appreciate a solution from my favourite place thanks.

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to install the latest rails gem

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.8
```

If it's a rails 3.2.3 app

1. Edit `Gemfile`, changing the line `gem 'rails', '3.2.3'` to `gem 'rails', '3.2.8'`
2. Run `bundle update rails`

(from [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898361/upgrading-rails-app-from-3-2-6-to-3-2-8))

Comment: Also just found this question. Worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: When updating the rails application, be sure to check http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/ to fix any possible errors or check for plugins, etc. that are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

For each app you want to upgrade:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
# ...
```

Then on the command line:

```
$ bundle update rails
```